SCDF 2.11.3 Job Executions menu not showing Spring Batch 5 application's job execution
I am new to Spring Cloud Data Flow.
I am using Spring Batch 5.1.1 version and have implemented some batch jobs.
To use monitoring and manual launches, I am trying to adopt SCDF for its purpose.
I realized that SCDF 2.11.3 automatically configures some tables at dedicated databases. But it seems like the default targeting schema is boot2, meaning that the tables being created are for spring batch 4.x, not 5.x. But there are also tables starting with prefix BOOT3_. These perfectly supports spring batch 5.x jobs....
I have managed my spring batch 5 application to use table-prefix of BOOT3_BATCH_ to resolve these issues, but SCDF's 'Job Executions' menu throws error like this:
error image
The error indicates that SCDF cannot find columns of spring batch 4's meta table format... how can I use SCDF for spring batch 5 applications to see Job Executions menu?
I also tried out with spring batch 4 application to apply with SCDF, and figured out that SCDF perfectly supports spring batch 4 job executions with 'Job Executions' menu.
I believe SCDF 2.11.3 supports spring batch 5. How can I utilize SCDF's 'Job Executions' menu with spring batch 5's meta table?

In order to use Spring Batch 5.x your application will be a Spring Boot 3.x application. This means when you register the application you should indicate the Spring Boot version as 3.x.
The table structures are not compatible between Batch 4 and Batch 5.
Then dataflow will provide the application with table prefixes to use to ensure it is updating the correct tables.

I actually have registered my application indicated as 3.x. However, the SCDF's default menu named 'Job Executions' seems to look up for a certain meta table of SCDF's. The problem here is that my SCDF's task execution does not create or manage the 'Job Executions' correctly.
I have tried out https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/batch-developer-guides/batch/data-flow-spring-batch/ this link's billrun example and it worked gracefully. The point is that this billrun is built in spring boot 2.7.7 with spring batch 4.x...

There are changes from Batch 4 to Batch 5 on how the job configuration works. I suggest working through https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html Create a basic unit test for your application to determine it is working as expected when running by itself on H2.

Thanks for the suggestion, but I have already tried out with basic demo project with spring batch 5. Unfortunately, spring batch 5 seems not compatible with SCDF's job Executions menu due to already-mapped SQL toward spring batch 4 meta table structure.

SCDF 2.11.x makes provision for having 2 sets of tables. Spring Batch and Spring Cloud Task provides for configuration of a table prefix. SCDF will provide the prefixes BOOT3_TASK_ and BOOT3_BATCH_ for applications registered as Boot 3.x applications while maintaining TASK_ and BATCH_ for Boot 2.x applications.

I do acknowledged that there are two provisions to support batch 5 and batch 4 via prefix. However, the 'JobExecutions' menu only looks out for batch 4 based meta tables(tables with no 'BOOT3_' prefixes).

I ran 2 sample batch apps each have 2 built-in jobs and queried with the following result.


22 job2 17 10 boot2 2024-06-20 12:24:47,000[+2] 1 COMPLETED


21 job1 17 9 boot2 2024-06-20 12:24:47,000[+2] 1 COMPLETED


18 job2 13 6 boot3 2024-06-20 12:24:56,383[+2] 1 COMPLETED


17 job1 13 5 boot3 2024-06-20 12:24:56,257[+2] 1 COMPLETED


